# Symfony 5: CSRF token is invalid

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, csrf-token

I know this has been asked many times before and I have been searching the web for the last hour but I can't find a solution.

What I'm trying to do is update my user data, in this case, my username.

I have profiler installed to check on errors and stuff like that, I haven't even submitted the form to change and I get an error that the token is invalid. I checked the source to see if it was even there and yes it was.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [suidgeest.eu](https://i.suidgeest.eu/qbocz7lb1nrd.png))</sub>

PS: Images are like this because I need 10 rep.

Comment: refresh the page to get a new CSRF token if its there, if its not getting posted with form data post it along with form data

Comment: @sumit I did get a new token if i look at the source code. and this is what I get after submitting the form (im guessing this is what you asked) https://i.suidgeest.eu/64vqmsmjzgap.png

Answer (score 0):

Check if your php session folder has the correct permissions, this happened to me before and that was it.

Comment: i dont have a sessions folder? nor has it ever existed. might that be the problem? if so, how would I set the permissions on localhost?

Comment: the php session folder depends on how you have your environment setup, i recommend you looking at this https://serverfault.com/questions/70634/what-permissions-ownership-to-set-on-php-sessions-folder-when-running-fastcgi it might help

Comment: The Symfony docs give you detailed information on setting up a web server: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html including how to set permissions. However, if this is happening on your local development then just use the symfony development server.  Permissions should not be an issue.